# Site-wide licence for QA org is reset in LMA on package upgrade

Tags: managed-package, isv, lma

For each of our customer apps, we create an `Enterprise org` for acceptance testing. We always create them using our ISV `Environment Hub`.

We now struggle with doing testing in one of those QA orgs as whenever we install a new package version its license is "reset" to **1 Admin Trial license** that does **expire soon**.

As a `PDO partner` who builds apps for a customer its cumbersome to ask the customer admin to make a change in the LMA in his PDO in such cases.

**What is the trick (the LMA setting) to allow enduring site-wide QA org licenses that continue to work after upgrades?**

> Note: I also asked this in the Salesforce Partner Community
>   https://partners.salesforce.com/0D53A00004lVz9A and opened Support
>   Case #25600549 with Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

Support says that only upgrade via Push (Major) Upgrade leave licenses untouched. And upgrade via AppExchange install link resets it. That doesn't resemble my past experience where we seldom used Push Upgrades. So I am confused.